# CsvHelper: Data Validation exceptions do not provide adequate information about exception to be helpful

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

When considering 'data' validation upon import of csv data using CsvHelper, I was hoping to put all of my 'data' validation code in the ClassMap using the .Validate method.

I am have been looking for good examples of how to use the .Validate method to ensure that the data conforms to my business rules and **also send good error message back to the user when validation rules have been violated**.

A very basic example is located in the 'Configuration/Class Maps/Validation code located in 'examples' section of the CsvHelper website located here: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/validation/

I am able to predictably able to make and catch errors that I have set up using the .Validate method.  However, I have not determined a way to give adequate information to my user to fix issues when they are encountered. It appears to me that the FieldValidationException does not contain enough information to be useful. I have seen others asking this question but the other posts that I have seen do not have an adequate answer to the problem.  Please see my code and comments below.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //  load comma separated data into string for processing
                var s = new StringBuilder();
                s.AppendLine("Id,Name");
                s.AppendLine("1,one-e");

                //  Begin processing
                using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
                    var contents = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Read file: length is : {contents.First().Id},{contents.First().Name},{contents.First().Date}");
                }
            }
            catch (FieldValidationException fieldExc)
            {
                //  this exception object does not appear to hold any information about the column that is in error. It does not seem to specify what the error entails.
                //  It appears to contain the value that created the exception?  In a 'string' field called: "Field". 
                //  I would really like further information about what is specifically is wrong with which column and possibly which row.
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Message is : {fieldExc.Message}");
            }
            catch(TypeConverterException converterExc)
            {
                //  If I happen to have a conversion exception, then the resulting TypeConversionException has good information to advise 
                //  a user to correct an error.
                var message = FriendlyErrorText(converterExc);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Message is : {exc.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test executed");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public class Foo
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset? Date { get; set; }
        }

        public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
        {
            public FooMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.Id);
                Map(m => m.Name).Validate(field => !field.Field.Contains("-"));
            }
        }

        public static string FriendlyErrorText(TypeConverterException exception)
        {
            var column = exception?.MemberMapData?.Member?.Name ?? "Unknown";
            string typeConversion;
            switch (exception?.TypeConverter?.ToString())
            {
                case "Int32Converter":
                    typeConversion = "integer";
                    break;
                default:
                    typeConversion = exception?.TypeConverter?.GetType()?.Name ?? "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
            var message = $"There was an error importing the text data '{exception?.Text ?? "Unknown"}' into the column {column}. The target column is of type {typeConversion}";
            return message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`FieldValidationException` includes the `CsvContext`, which has most of what you would need.

```cs
catch (FieldValidationException fieldExc)
{
    var message = string.Empty;
    var headerIndex = fieldExc.Context.Reader.CurrentIndex;
    if(fieldExc.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord[headerIndex].ToLower() == "name")
    {
        message = "Name cannot contain a dash.";
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Error Message is : Field Validation Exception on Row: {fieldExc.Context.Parser.Row}, Message: {message} Original Text: \"{fieldExc.Field}\"");
}
```